# Is there a way to change the default return path with sendmail?

Tags: sendmail, return-path

I know that I can use the -f switch to set the return path with sendmail, I am wondering if it is possible to change the default return path somewhere, or if the only way is to set it per send.

Comment: sendmail is a system-wide utility. if you change it at the sendmail level, **ALL** email from the system will get that new setting. you'd be better off leaving it alone and doing the override with `-f` in your app.

Comment: that is what I want, so instead of any email coming from a nonsense address when -f is not set (nobody@mydomain.com), it comes from support@mydomain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`FEATURE(genericstable)`](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#genericstable) to rewrite sender addresses.

By default genericstable changes only "header sender" addresses.

[FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#masquerade_envelope) turns on also rewriting "envelope sender" address (which may be set by `-f`)

[FEATURE(allmasquerade)](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#allmasquerade) turns on also rewriting "header recipients" (addresses in `To:` and `Cc:` headers)

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading_relaying.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using apache2 and virtual hosts - in every *.vhost file in /etc/apache2/sites-available
you can set ServerAdmin address.
This record apache using to set Return-Path header address.